# Elasticsearch Prefix Exact Match

Tags: elasticsearch

i have text fields like above

```
elastic|b|c
elastic,search|b|c
elastic,search,prefix|b|c
```

I want to query on this string with prefix. And the query is

```
aggs":{  
   "field":{  
      "filter":{  
         "match":{  
            "field":{  
               "type":"prefix",
               "query":"elastic|"
            }
         }
      },
      "aggs":{  
         "field":{  
            "terms":{  
               "field":"textField",
               "size":255
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
},
"
```

and this query return all texts below in the example. 
**Do i need extra analyzer or token filter on texts?**
How can i exact match search with prefix on elastic ?

Comment: related : https://discuss.elastic.co/t/prefix-query-exact-match/75836

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that by using wildcards in elasticsearch.

```
{
  "query": {
"wildcard": {
      "textField": {
        "value": "elastic*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```